# AT Command - How to specify more than one occurrence

Tags: windows

How do you specify more than one occurrence using the "AT" command e.g.

run xxxx.exe every 20 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Instead of AT use a scheduled task.

In Windows 7 / 2008 use the Task Scheduler (under Administrative tools)

Pre Windows 2 / 2008 go to Scheduled Tasks (also under Administrative tools)

Comment: scheduled task - I hate them :(

Comment: @James Why?  They do exactly what you're looking to do?

Comment: The at command is actually just an interface to the Task Scheduler... and not a particularly powerful one.